# Reduce space between header and headrule

Tags: spacing, header-footer, boxes, fancyhdr

## Problem

I'm trying to create fancy headers for my documents using `fancyhdr`. I want the headrule to be dotted, which can be achieved using

```
\renewcommand{\headrule}{\vbox to 0pt{\hbox to\headwidth{\dotfill}\vss}}
```

as stated in the `fancyhdr`-documentation on page 12. Now I also want to move the rule nearer to the content of the header. For the footer, there is `\footruleskip`
, but unfortunately no <s>`\footruleskip`</s>. If I just elevate the box of the headrule by using `\raisebox` I get

```
Package Fancyhdr Warning: \headheight is too small (38.32509pt): 
 Make it at least 39.58127pt.
```

How do I automatically adjust `\headheight` or how can I get rid of the overfull box produced by raising the headrule box.

*Bonus:* Currently I specify `\setlength{\headheight}{3.5em}` because of the `\Huge\thechapter`. How can I automatically set `\headheight`?

## MWE

```
\documentclass{scrbook}
% Display box around header
\usepackage{eso-pic}
\AddToShipoutPictureFG{
    \AtTextUpperLeft{%
        \put(0,\LenToUnit{\headsep}){%
            \framebox(\LenToUnit{\textwidth},\LenToUnit{\headheight}){}%
        }%
    }%
}

\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\pagestyle{fancy}

\setlength{\headheight}{3.5em}

% From fancyhdr documentation
\fancyhf{}
\fancyhead[LE,RO]{\sffamily\chaptername\ \Huge\thechapter}
\fancyhead[RE,LO]{\sffamily\leftmark}
\begin{document}

\chapter{Test Chapter}
\eject

\renewcommand{\headrule}{\vbox to 0pt{\hbox to\headwidth{\dotfill}\vss}}
\hbox{}
\eject

\renewcommand{\headrule}{\raisebox{0.25\headheight}{\vbox to 0pt{\hbox to\headwidth{\dotfill}\vss}}}
\hbox{}

\end{document}
```

## Output

`\renewcommand{\headrule}{\vbox to 0pt{\hbox to\headwidth{\dotfill}\vss}}`

> [image]

`\renewcommand{\headrule}{\raisebox{0.25\headheight}{\vbox to 0pt{\hbox to\headwidth{\dotfill}\vss}}}`

> [image]

Comment: If you `\smash{\Huge\thechapter}` and use `\renewcommand{\headrule}{\raisebox{0.25\headheight}{\makebox[\headwidth]{\dotfill}}}`, then I don't get any warnings. You still have to set `\headheight` manually.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use the center field, without redefining `\headrule`:

```
\documentclass{scrbook}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\usepackage{picture} % directly specify lengths with their unit in picture commands
\usepackage{lipsum}
% Display box around header
\usepackage{eso-pic}
\AddToShipoutPictureFG{
    \AtTextUpperLeft{%
        \put(0,\headsep){%
            \framebox(\textwidth,\headheight){}%
        }%
    }%
}

\pagestyle{fancy}
\setlength{\headheight}{24.4pt}
\newcommand{\dotrule}{%
  \makebox[0pt][l]{%
    \hspace{-.5\textwidth}%
    \raisebox{-8pt}{%
      \makebox[\textwidth][l]{%
        \kern-.00625\textwidth
        \xleaders\hbox to 0.0125\textwidth{\hss.\hss}\hfill
        \kern-.00625\textwidth
      }%
    }%
  }%
}

% From fancyhdr documentation
\fancyhf{}
\fancyhead[LE,RO]{\sffamily\chaptername\ {\Huge\thechapter}}
\fancyhead[RE,LO]{\sffamily\leftmark}
\fancyhead[C]{\dotrule}
\renewcommand\headrulewidth{0pt}
\begin{document}

\chapter{Test Chapter}
\lipsum

\end{document}
```

I defined “by hand” the dot filling, because `\xleaders` should be used.

[image]

Personal comment: I rarely saw something this ugly.

Comment: Thank you for your answer and your opinion. I'm trying to recreate the pagestyle of this [thesis (70MB)](http://beta.nicolailang.de/content/Media_Content/Physik/Theses/Master-Thesis_-_Phase_transitions_and_topological_phases_by_driven_dissipation.pdf). Do you have any suggestions for a more pleasing header? How do you get the `24.4pt` for `\headheight`?

Comment: @HenriMenke Just don't set `\headheight` (or set it to zero) and look in the `.log` file for the warning `fancyhdr` emits.

Comment: @HenriMenke The layout is not bad, but it has many defects. The chapter number in the header is too big; the dots have no place either. Usage of color is inconsistent: it doesn't make sense to use gray *and* colored backgrounds. The equations with a background have the equation number misplaced. Some notes are introduced by a blue title, others by a title with a dotted line. Skimming through it gives an overall impression of inconsistency.